# Changing magento template system

Tags: xml, templates, magento, block

The task is next:
We need to change  template system logic so it would be much easier for buliding up templates.
In example:
Request: www.example.com/index.php
System parses adress and the output should be something like this:

```
    getChildHtml(header);
    getChildHtml(indexContent);
    getChildHtml(footer);
```

As i understood I need to deal with XML layout. If I am correct I need to remove all and then build my own logic of blocks? By then how magento will understand that for example when customer_logged_in it needs to take some block, while customer_logged_in handle doesn't exists?

How Block_Class files are connected with xml layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the layout, when you declare a block, you set its type. That's the class of the block.
For instance, if you have 

the class of this block is Mage_Core_Block_Template
Or if it's 

the class is Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart.

Hope this helps.